# Can I install a Mac OS X application which I signed as developer on any Apple computer?

Tags: ios, macos, certificate

On https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.php I read that if I sign an iOS application as developer I can install the application (without using AppStore) only on "100 iOS devices for testing and Ad Hoc distribution per membership year."

Does the same limitation exist also for Mac OS X application? Or can I - once I signed my Mac OS X application  as developer - install it without limitations (and without changing default Gatekeeper settings) on any Apple computer?

Comment: Now you've edited your answer "(and without changing default Gatekeeper settings"..." it is no longer clear as to what you are asking.

Comment: I want to sign my application as developer and then be sure, that my users can install my app (which is not distributed via App Store) without seeing any error messages from Gatekeeper. This should work. However, somebody told me, that I cannot install the app on more than 100 computers, even if I signed my app. And I'm asking if this is true for Mac OS X apps or if this is true only for iOS apps.

Comment: I believe that is only a restriction of iOS, as you cannot distribute iOS apps outside of the App Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the same does not apply and there is no limitation on numbers of users that can run the application.

OSX has a feature known as "Gatekeeper". If you look in System Preferences and select the "Security and Privacy" option, under the General tab you'll see that there's a control which allows apps to run depending upon their origin: -

[image]

If the "Mac App Store" option is selected and your application has not been downloaded from the App Store, then OS X will prevent it running.

The "...identified developers" will allow apps from the App Store and any apps signed by a registered developer to run. You do not need your app to be distributed via the App Store with this setting, which is one of the reasons you have a developer certificate.

Finally, if "Anywhere" is selected, then your app will run regardless of where it originated, or whether or not it is signed.

Should your app do something malicious, Apple can revoke your developer certificate and machines set to any option above "Anywhere" will stop your app from running.

Comment: So for Mac OS X once I signed my application with my developer certificate I can distribute it without any limits?

Comment: Correct. The only limit then is if you distribute it outside of the App Store and the user has Gatekeeper set to only run App Store apps. When trying to run your app, they will be notified of this.

Answer (score 0):

Also to install an app on a iOS device you have to add it to a developer profile and in developer profile you can add only 100 device pro year.
On a Mac you don't need to create a certificate, so you can develop your OS X app and you can install it on all Mac you want without any limitations (the only limitations it's the hardware or technical limitations for example: old Mac can't run an app you developed with a new Mac, indeed they have a different CPU).
You need to be an OS X developer to public your app on the Mac App Store.
I hope my answer will help you